# base64 encoding with limited line length as per RFC2045

Tags: go, base64

RFC2045 section 6.8 states maximum encoded line length of base64 output should be 76 characters or less.

The Golang stream writer `base64.NewEncoder` does not have any option for line splitting, as can be seen here.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)


// See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt, section 6.8 for notes on maximum line length of 76 characters
func main() {
    data := "It is only the hairs on a gooseberry that prevent it from being a grape! This is long enough to need a line split"
    rdr := strings.NewReader(data)
    wrt := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, os.Stdout)
    io.Copy(wrt, rdr)
}
```

Output is

```
SXQgaXMgb25seSB0aGUgaGFpcnMgb24gYSBnb29zZWJlcnJ5IHRoYXQgcHJldmVudCBpdCBmcm9tIGJlaW5nIGEgZ3JhcGUhIEl0IGlzIG9ubHkgdGhlIGhhaXJzIG9uIGEgZ29vc2ViZXJyeSB0aGF0IHByZXZlbnQgaXQgZnJvbSBiZWluZyBhIGdyYXBl
```

Is there a **stream-based solution** to splitting lines?
The [MIME library](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#WordDecoder.Decode) offers only string based encoding options.

Comment: Not stream based, but maybe something can be hacked out using encoding/pem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt to create a simple `Writer`. It takes into account varying amounts of input data, has configurable chunk length and separator sequence. It uses byte-slice writes for the chunks, which will hopefully be efficient.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func min(a, b int) int {
    if a < b {
        return a
    }
    return b
}

type linesplitter struct {
    len   int
    count int
    sep   []byte
    w     io.Writer
}

// NewWriter that splits input every len bytes with a sep byte sequence, outputting to writer w
func (ls *linesplitter) NewWriter(len int, sep []byte, w io.Writer) io.WriteCloser {
    return &linesplitter{len: len, count: 0, sep: sep, w: w}
}

// Split a line in to ls.len chunks with separator
func (ls *linesplitter) Write(in []byte) (n int, err error) {
    writtenThisCall := 0
    readPos := 0
    // Leading chunk size is limited by: how much input there is; defined split length; and
    // any residual from last time
    chunkSize := min(len(in), ls.len-ls.count)
    // Pass on chunk(s)
    for {
        ls.w.Write(in[readPos:(readPos + chunkSize)])
        readPos += chunkSize // Skip forward ready for next chunk
        ls.count += chunkSize
        writtenThisCall += chunkSize

        // if we have completed a chunk, emit a separator
        if ls.count >= ls.len {
            ls.w.Write(ls.sep)
            writtenThisCall += len(ls.sep)
            ls.count = 0
        }
        inToGo := len(in) - readPos
        if inToGo <= 0 {
            break // reached end of input data
        }
        // Determine size of the NEXT chunk
        chunkSize = min(inToGo, ls.len)
    }
    return writtenThisCall, nil
}

func (ls *linesplitter) Close() (err error) {
    return nil
}

// See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt, section 6.8 for notes on maximum line length of 76 characters
func main() {
    data := "It is only the hairs on a gooseberry that prevent it from being a grape! This is long enough to need a line split"
    shortData := "hello there"

    var ls linesplitter
    lsWriter := ls.NewWriter(76, []byte("\r\n"), os.Stdout)
    wrt := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, lsWriter)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        io.Copy(wrt, strings.NewReader(shortData))
        io.Copy(wrt, strings.NewReader(data))
        io.Copy(wrt, strings.NewReader(shortData))
    }
}
```

... comments/improvements welcome.

Comment: "simple Writer class" -- Note, this is not a class. Go doesn't have classes. It would be better to call it (and think of it as) a type instead.

Comment: Thanks, keep forgetting that. I think it's a method that acts on a type.

Comment: `io.WriteCloser` is an interface. Interfaces are types. Your implementation is a type, which happens to be a struct, with the necessary methods.

Comment: BTW, I don't think there's any reason for you to return an `io.WriteCloser` as opposed to just an `io.Writer`.

Comment: Thanks. I have made it a Writer and removed my Close method as it does nothing. Update in https://github.com/tuck1s/go-smtpproxy/blob/c7885f44b04c998d4bac20b953030ed61b6dca69/linesplitter.go#L24